# mysql how to create optimum query for these table

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables.

```
TABLE book_tittle 
id INT(11),
title VARCHAR(256),
writer_id INT(11)
```

```
TABLE favorite_writer
id INT(11),
user_id INT(11),
favorite_writer_id INT(11),
favorite_writer_name VARCHAR(256)
```

there are hundreds of thousand data in both tables.

what i want to do is, when a user want to search a tittle book. they will see the tittle book and SORT by their favorite writer.

offcourse for example, if user with id=10 want to search book tittle which contain word "something" i can do sql like this :

```
select * 
from book_tittle 
where tittle like "&something%" 
where writer_id in (select favorite_writer_id 
from favorite_writer 
where user_id=10);
```

the problem is, both of tables are contain hundreds of thousands data (and keep increasing). if 1 user has 10,000 favorite writer, this query would become very slow. is there any better way to solve it ?

also, if none of the favorite writer create book with title like that, i hope i would see any book (event if the writer is not my favorite user)

many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an outer join and order by the favorite author id.  This would return all of your books that match the title search, with the users favorite author books at the top.

```
select b.*, f.favorite_writer_id
from book_tittle b
left outer join favorite_writer f on b.writer_id = f.writer_id and f.user_id = 10
where b.tittle like '%something%'
order by f.favorite_writer_id asc
```

But thats just another approach for the query itself.  Overall you should look into the suggestions on other answers as well in terms of tweaking your data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Working with what you've got there, you could try something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM book_tittle
LEFT JOIN favourite_writer
ON book_tittle . writer_id = favourite_writer . id
WHERE favourite_writer . user_id = 10
AND book_tittle . tittle LIKE "%something%";
```

That should return one row for each book with a title that contains `something`. Each row should include data for columns from both the `book_tittle` and `favourite_writer` tables.

As long as you have relevant primary keys and indexes, a query like that shouldn't be *too* slow.

If you do find that it's slow, try executing the query in the mysql command line interface, prefixing it with `[EXPLAIN][1]`. If you're not using `primary keys` or `indexes`, you should be.

Here are a few links that may help you with learning about keys:

- http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Key/Defineanduseprimarykey.htm

### Recommendation:

You should have another table, `authors` maybe like:

```
TABLE authors
id INT ( which is referenced in book_tittle . writer_id )
name VARCHAR
```

That stores the authors.

Your `favourite_writer` table could then look like:

```
TABLE favourite_writer
author_id INT ( authors . id )
user_id INT
```

This table forms a link between authors and users who like them.

Finally, read up on [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)